Midpoint polygon for odd $n$

Given $n$ distinct points $M_1, M_2, M_3, \dots, M_n$ in an affine space $U$; in  case $n$ is odd, it's possible to find $A_1,\dots,A_n \in U$ such that $M_1$ is the midpoint of $\overline{A_1A_2}$, $M_2$ is the midpoint of $\overline{A_2A_3}$, ...,$M_n$ is the midpoint of $\overline{A_1A_n}$.

If $n=3$ and $M_1,M_2,M_3$ aren't collinear, then  $M_1M_2M_3$ is the medial triangle of $A_1A_2A_3$, so the points $A_1, A_2,A_3$ would be unique. But it's the only case that I can properly justify. Any suggestions?

We solve the pentagonal case by a reduction process, then show that this process can be iterated to solve for any odd number of sides.
For the pentagonal case let $M_1,...M_5$ be the given midpoints. Then $M_1$ and $M_2$ are also midpoints of two sides of a triangle $A_1A_2A_3$ in which two sides $\overline{A_1A_2},\overline{A_2A_3}$ are also two adjacent sides of the pentagon and the third side $\overline{A_3A_1}$ is a diagonal of the pentagon. This pentagon diagonal/triangle side has a currently unknown midpoint $X$.
The diagonal $\overline{A_3A_1}$ also splits off a quadrilateral $A_3A_4A_5A_1$ whose side midpoints are $M_3,M_4,M_5$ and the aforementioned unknown point $X$ on the diagonal. But now we see that the side midpoints of the quadrilateral must be vertices of a parallelogram. So given the three midpoints $M_3,M_4,M_5$ we find $X$ by constructing the appropriate parallels to $\overline{M_3M_4}$ and $\overline{M_4M_5}$.
$\triangle A_1A_2A_3$ has side midpoints $M_1,M_2,X$ where $X$ is now known, so we can construct the triangle and thus obtain three of the pentagon vertices $A_1,A_2,A_3$. With these plus the midpoints of the remaining sides the known the construction of a unique pentagon follows. QED for the pentagonal case.
Now we can iterate this process. Say we have a heptagon with known side midpoints $M_1,...M_7$. Then we have a pentagon with side midpoints $M_1,...,M_4,X$ and a set-off quadrilateral with side midpoints $M_5,M_6,M_7,X$ which again must be vertices of a parallelogram. So we find $X$ from the quadrilateral and thereby reduce the problem to solving the pentagon, which is then reducible to a triangle. Similarly any $n$-gon with $n$ odd is reducible in decrements of two until the construction can be rebuilt from a triangular solution.

Is there any way without using that ' the side midpoints of the quadrilateral must be vertices of a parallelogram'?

Should I reduce the case above splitting the quadrilater into two triangles?

No. You do not split the quadrilateral. You can only decrement $n$ by twos, so geometrically the set-off quadrilaterals must remain whole and you use the parallelogram property on them.

"Is there any way without using that ' the side midpoints of the quadrilateral must be vertices of a parallelogram'?" If you have coordonates of the midpoints you can set up and solce a linear system of equations. The determinant of the coefficient matrix is $1-(-1)^n$, hence you get a unique solution iff $n$ is odd.
